# Cannot access tomcat's manager webapp

Tags: tomcat

This question has been asked at least 5 times here or at stackoverflow, but in virtually all cases either a pre tomcat7 version causes trouble or the tomcat-users.xml is syntactically incorrect. I'd appreciate it if you help me find my errors.

I'm running tomcat 7.0.52-1 with openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My users config file is [here](http://pastebin.com/9GZ6s3T2).

Yet when I visit

```
http://localhost:8080
```

and click "Manager App", I get an Error 401.
Any ideas?

PS I edited my tomcat-users.xml . I added

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
```

and I also changed my

```
<user username="tomcat-gui" password="tomcat-gui" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

to

```
<user username="tomcat-gui" password="tomcat-gui" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

Comment: Check if you have the directory with name `manager` inside the directory `webapps` in your tomcat install.

Comment: No, there is no such path. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ubuntu IRC support, someone pointed out I have erroneous config data. 
If you look at my very first tomcat-users.xml, you will see that two `role` tags are not matched. So I fixed that and it now all works fine.

PS Editing server.xml was not necessary at all; furthermore, I suggest to anyone using tomcat version 7 and above to avoid defining roles not described in the official documentation. Especially, I have found several forum threads and blogs on the Net reccomending adding `admin` as a role, which will not work since `admin` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `apt-get` to install tomcat, you must add manager with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin
```

Then can access the manager in `http://your_ip_address:8080/manager/html`

see also: [How To Install Apache Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 via Apt-Get](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get)

Comment: I just skimmed throught the guide and installed the required packages. I also updated my config. Yet I still cannot access the manager.

Comment: try with `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

Comment: Neither adress wants to do the job, unfortunately. I appreciate your efforts nonetheless.

Comment: check files `/etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml` and directory `/usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager`, after any change in the configuration you must restart the tomcat.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1nwjGJnJ is the manager.xml file and the path specified in the file is also available. It is the same as the one you have pointed out.

Comment: @learningtech do you have any message in logs during start tomcat or when you try access?

Comment: I start tomcat with the service command, which does not return any messages. But you can find the whole log for today here: http://pastebin.com/N14H3ySH

Comment: @learningtech You have error 401 unauthorized. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763560/401-unauthorized-error-while-logging-in-manager-app-of-tomcat

Comment: check this http://chandank.com/application-server/tomcat/tomcat-login-problem

Comment: Following the instructions given at the link above did not resolve the login problem. Worse yet - by adding <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" /> to the server.xml file, I caused tomcat to fail to (re)start.